# How can I compare a real number to a column in a tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I am trying to use `runif()` to generate a set of random probabilities and then compare it to the list of cumulative probabilities in a tibble so that I can lookup the expected market return. Is there a tidyverse way of comparing the random probability to see if it is equal to or less than one of the values in the CumulativeProb column.

```
CumulativeProb <- scan(text = '0.12, 0.52,0.77,0.92,1.00', sep = ',')
MarketReturn <- scan(text = '0.23,0.18,0.15,0.09,0.03', sep = ',')
df1 <- tibble::tibble(CumulativeProb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the following is what the question asks for.

The code below uses `findInterval` to determine where in the cumulative probabilities a vector of numbers in the interval `[0, 1]` lies, returning the interval's index.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(MarketReturn = MarketReturn,
         Where = findInterval(MarketReturn, CumulativeProb, left.open = TRUE, rightmost.closed = TRUE) + 1L)
## A tibble: 5 x 3
#  CumulativeProb MarketReturn Where
#           <dbl>        <dbl> <int>
#1           0.12         0.23     2
#2           0.52         0.18     2
#3           0.77         0.15     2
#4           0.92         0.09     1
#5           1            0.03     1
```